# What EventId can i put when calling ILogger.LogError from Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using injected instance of ILogger instead of TraceWritter. The instance is injected fromm the Azure Function Runtime. I want to log a captured exception. The only overload of LogError that can accept a Exception is the extension method from class LoggerExtensions:

```
void LogError(this ILogger logger, EventId eventId, Exception exception, string message, params object[] args)
```

The problem is: this method receive a EventId as second argument, **from where i can take the current EventId to use here**? (I suppose each AF execution has his unique EventId).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an overload which just accepts a string:

```
void LogError(this ILogger logger, string message, params object[] args);
```

If you need an overload with `Exception`, just pass `(EventId) 0` to it (that's what other overloads do).

Comment: I preffer to use an overload thats accepts a parameter with the exception. For now I calling thats overload passing default(EventId) as value for the eventId.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method like this:

```
using System;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
{
    public static class LoggerExtensions
    {
        public static void LogError(this ILogger logger, Exception ex, string message = null, params object[] args)
        {
            logger.LogError(default(EventId), ex, message, args);
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/367#issuecomment-313805976